# What is a megahash and how is it used to estimate the rate at which bitcoins are mined?

Tags: hash, mining-theory, hashpower, investing

What part of the bitcoin network requires hashes and why? What is the relation between money and the megahashes a card can do?

Answer (score 6):

A hash is a function that takes a string as an input, does a transformation of it, and returns a second string that's considerably shorter than the original and that could be considered is the "resume" of the original. You can check [Wikipedia's Hash definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Hashes are required for "mining". I'm new to Bitcoin so I may describe this wrongly: As part of mining, miners compete to discover a short number that, when added to the end of a string (which contains all recent transactions since 10 minutes ago) produces a hash with a specific number of zeros at the beginning. The correctness of such a discovery can be easily verified by anyone but finding that small apendix is computationally very, very hard. The first miner to discover such a key to "lock" a block is awarded the reward - 25 BTCs as of now.

Here in comes the "mega-hash" term: CPUs, arrays of GPUs and ASICs are rated according to how many different hashes they can compute per second. Analyzing a million different hashes per second is what's called a "mega-hash". Obviously, the higher this number the more different combinatinos you can try, so it becomes more probable that you will find an answer. However, this is only a relative advantage that may be completely nullified if the other miners have a similar or even higher computing power than yours.

This graph explains it all beautifully, hope it's clearer than my bad prose [image: How bitcoins work]